# Informix fetch using rivet not returning end of query results

Tags: sql, c, apache, tcl, informix

We are having an issue running Tclsql code from a web page using Rivet and Informix.

When we run the TCL code that executes the query from a command line script, it works.  The Informix C library fetch sets the value of sqlca.sqlcode to 100 after it has fetch the last row of data.  Then, the tclsql C library sets the result string to "", which is what the command line TCL script uses to determine that all of the results have been fetched.

When we run the same script from a browser using Rivet, the Informix C library fetch does not set the sqlca.sqlcode value to 100 after it has fetched the last row of results.  Instead, it sets it to 0, indicating that there are more results, and returns the last query result to the tclsql C library, which then returns the last query result to the TCL script that we ran from the browser (instead of "").

Here is the script that we run from the command line:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Next line restarts using tclsh \
exec /BSG/local/bin/tclsh "$0" "$@"

package require Tclsql

sql database devncrs

set query "SELECT count(*) FROM district"

set cur [sql open $query]

while { [set result [sql fetch $cur 1]] != "" } {
    puts $result
}

sql close $cur
```

The query should return 110 (which is the count for the table) to the TCL script above and then return a "", which it does.

Here is the script that we run from the browser:

```
package require Tclsql

sql database devncrs

set query "SELECT count(*) FROM district"

set cur [sql open $query]

while { [set result [sql fetch $cur 1]] != "" } {
    puts "<br>result = '$result`"
}

sql close $cur
```

This code gets stuck in and endless while loop because it never gets "" back
from the tclsql C library.

We compiled rivet, TCL, and Informix on the same LINUX box using the same version of the OS and installed Apache with the lampp package.

Here is the environment:

```
OS: Linux dev-ncrs-web4 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 6 19:56:57 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Apache version: 2.4.27
Rivet version: 2.3.4
TCL version: 8.6.6
Informix version: 4.10
```

Here are the libraries being used by libtclsql.so, libsqlinf.o, and mod_rivet.so

```
ldd libsqlinf.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe691e0000)
    libixsql.so => /usr/informix/lib/esql/libixsql.so (0x00007f6426bab000)
    libixasf.so => /usr/informix/lib/libixasf.so (0x00007f6426962000)
    libixgen.so => /usr/informix/lib/esql/libixgen.so (0x00007f64266fe000)
    libixos.so => /usr/informix/lib/esql/libixos.so (0x00007f64264dd000)
    libixgls.so => /usr/informix/lib/esql/libixgls.so (0x00007f642628a000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f6426053000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6425d51000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f642598d000)
    libfreebl3.so => /usr/lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f642578a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055862238b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6425586000)

ldd libtclsql.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe22fc5000)
    libsqlinf.so (0x00007ff9a85b0000)
    libtcl8.6.so => /BSG/local/lib/libtcl8.6.so (0x00007ff9a8201000)
    libixsql.so => /usr/informix/lib/esql/libixsql.so (0x00007ff9a7fad000)
    libixasf.so => /usr/informix/lib/libixasf.so (0x00007ff9a7d65000)
    libixgen.so => /usr/informix/lib/esql/libixgen.so (0x00007ff9a7b00000)
    libixos.so => /usr/informix/lib/esql/libixos.so (0x00007ff9a78df000)
    libixgls.so => /usr/informix/lib/esql/libixgls.so (0x00007ff9a768d000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007ff9a7455000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff9a7153000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff9a6f4f000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff9a6d38000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff9a6b1c000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff9a6759000)
    libfreebl3.so => /usr/lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007ff9a6555000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055873ec47000)

ldd mod_rivet.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdbfbf2000)
    libtcl8.6.so => /BSG/local/lib/libtcl8.6.so (0x00007fcd949e0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcd947db000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fcd945c5000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcd943a9000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcd940a6000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcd93ce3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056435fdca000)
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem or have any idea what might be causing the fetch, as it is executed through rivet, to not set the value of sqlca.sqlcode to 100 after the last result has been fetched?  We had similar results when we ran a query that returned more than one row.

Comment: The web server is probably running as a different user. Does that user have the correct environment to connect to the DB?

Comment: You can try getting a SQLIDEBUG trace for both cases and compare the output. SQLIDEBUG will trap every package sent between server and client, the SQLCODE 100 should be there (at the end of the SQ_FETCH). To enable just set SQLIDEBUG env variable to something like '2:/tmp/sqli'.  More info here:  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21104625

Comment: Glenn, I ran the queries again using SQLIDEBUG and use SQLIPRINT to look at the SQLIDEBUG ouput.  My comment space is very limited.  Can I email you directly to show you what the results were?  If so, please send me your email to norris.george@yahoo.com.  Once I solve this problem, I will make sure the solution makes its way back here.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I am going to call a workaround for this problem.  I modified the tclsql.c and sqlinf.ec files that we u
se.

The TCL SQL "sql fetch" calls a function in the isqltcl4.0 library tclsql.c file named tcl_sql_fetch.
The tcl_sql_fetch function calls a function in the isqltcl4.0 library sqlinf.ec file named sql_fetch.

The sql_fetch function executes the fetch on the Informix database server it and a row is fetched.  If there are no m
ore rows to fetch, the sql server code should set the value of sqlca.sqlcode to 100.  When we ran a TCL fetch from a 
TCL script run from the command line, it worked fine.  When we ran the same TCL code from a browser using rivet and a
pache, the value of sqlca.sqlcode was always set to 0. This caused the code in the tclsql.c tcl_sql_fetch function to
 think that there were more rows to fetch and it did not return a blank result string "".  Instead, it return the las
t value fetched over and over again.   As a result, the TCL script while loop never stopped.

Here is the code that sets returns the value from the sqlinf.ec sql_fetch function to the tclsqlc tcl_sql_fetch funct
ion:

```
ret = sqlca.sqlcode;
chk_status("FETCH(OPEN)", ssql[fd].cmd);
return ret;
```

The sqlca.sqlcode was never set to 100 when the script was run from a browser.

To remedy this, I added wrote a new sql_fetch function in sqlinf.ec named "bnc_sql_fetch" and passed it an integer value

```
int bnc_sql_fetch(fd, bnc_fetch_count)
```

I added a static integer to the tclsql.c file named bnc_fetch_count. The bnc_fetch_count static int variable was initialized to 0 in the tcl_sql_open function in tclsql.c and incremented by 1 each time the bnc_sql_fetch function was called.

Then, in the bnc_sql_fetch function, I check the value of bnc_fetch_count against that of the first element in the integer array sqlca.sqlerrd, which contains the total number of rows to be fetched.  If it was greater than the total number of rows to be fetched, then the last row had been fetch and it returns 100.

```
if ( bnc_fetch_count > sqlca.sqlerrd[0] ) {
    ret = 100;
    chk_status("FETCH(OPEN)", ssql[fd].cmd);
    return ret;
}
```

This fixed the problem.